# Excel column functionality

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

i was looking for a function in Excel to do the following thing.

I have a list with EAN codes (they're all in column A) with every EAN code there is a description of what it is (descriptions are all in column B) here is what i want, if i search for a EAN code lets say i set my search in "C1" i want it to search in column A that EAN code and set the description (what's in column B) of that EAN code in "D1".

Is this possible and how do i do this. I searched already but i can't find it. Maybe it isn't possible maybe it is. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO.Please share code snippets of what you have tried so far and what you observe and expect the code to behave.

Comment: This sounds like you want to type an EAN code into C1 and have the description (from column B) from a match to the EAN codes in column A appear in D1. see [VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I always do this with an INDEX / MATCH combo. VLOOKUP would also work, but I've always found the INDEX/MATCH more intuitive for some reason. For **D1**, I'd use:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$300,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$300,0))
```

Replace both '300's with the last row of your dataset.  The '0' in MATCH requests an exact match from the lookup range, here $A$1:$A$300, regardless of sort order.